# Canvas background color not saved

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Tkinter canvas.postscript is not saving the canvas background.

Sizes of the canvas that are used throughout the Python code:

```
w = 800
h = 600
```

Function to be assigned to "SAVE CANVAS' button:

```
def save_canvas():
    canvas.update()
    canvas.postscript(file= r'Z:\\...\FILE.ps', height=h, width=w, colormode='color')
```

When I click on the button that has the save_canvas command assign, the file that is saved has no background as assigned in the widget. I changed the color to orange, green, etc. draw on it. Everything looks ok, but saving is without background. Same with .jpeg/.png

What do I need to call for saving the background? I'll be needing this as the application I build require images as background as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the `postscript` command is designed to preserve the background color of the canvas widget. It only saves the items that appear on the canvas.

A simple solution is to draw a rectangle that is the exact size of the canvas, and change the color of that rectangle.